# CSS3 and Heroku

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, css, heroku

I am having a problem with CSS3 code and heroku. I am currently hosting my website temporary on heroku, and this piece of code doesn't not seem to work:

```
#my_footer
{
    margin-top:170px;
    background-color:rgba(17,142,36,0.3); /* added this because of the backgroud */
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

especially this line of code: background-color:rgba(17,142,36,0.3); the strange part is that it works on my localhost, but not on heroku! and I am using the same browser!

Note: I have checked the code on GitHub and the code is EXACTLY as above! so when I push to heroku, and then check the source code from the browser, the code for "my_footer" is NOT the same as the one in GitHub!! It is like GitHub is not pushing my code to heroku!!

btw I have this in my config/environments/production.rb

```
...
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true #changed to true!
...
```

otherwise heroku returns me an error, and does not display the page if it is 'false' I am using twitter bootstrap btw!

Thanks!

Comment: On which Heroku stack and Rails version are you running on?

Comment: Do you have some caching layer (like memcached) turned on?

Comment: "Do you have some caching layer (like memcached) turned on? " have no idea. I am still new to Rails 3

Comment: Try to log on heroku and clear the cache:

_(from your app's root)_

`heroku console`

then type

`Rails.cache.clear`

Comment: Last time I looked, Github didn't push to Heroku. Maybe that's changed, but when I did it you had to push explicitly to Heroku `$ git push heroku master`. You can go see if Heroku has the same file with `heroku console` then go cat the file that Heroku has.

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti I am trying Rails.cache.clear
but i get this "No such file or directory - /app/tmp/cache/"

Comment: Yesterday there has been a problem on Heroku API that prevented push commands to succeed. Try again today.

Answer (score 0):

try to run `rake assets:precompile` on your locale machine.
After add the generated files to git

```
git add .
git commit -m "assets precompiled"
git push heroku master
```

assuming your remote branch is called 'heroku'.